# keepalived + MySQL with periodic  MISC_CHECK

Tags: mysql

I have  Keepalived + MySQL (master - master) setup done.

I have kept the priority same for MASTER and BACKUP because I don't want them to start flapping frequently (one time switch of VIP is good enough).

This setup works fine if I use the simple 'vrrp-script' to check if mysql daemon is down. e.g.

```
script to check mysql daemon
vrrp_script chk_mysql {
   script "killall -0 mysqld"      # verify the pid is exist or not
   interval 2                           # check every 2 seconds
   weight 2
}
```

I want to make it work with deeper health check with one python script. I want to use MISC_CHECK for that.

e.g.

```
 MISC_CHECK {
           misc_path “script_to_call_python_script.sh xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx”
           misc_timeout  5
        }
```

My query is:

1. How can I make the MISC_CHECK to run at specified intervals?
2. Otherwise, what is 'required' output of script in 'vrrp_script', so that I could run 
    shell script there (which runs are periodic interval)?

Answer (score 1):

Place the python code in a folder and in your vrrp_script call it like

```
vrrp_script chk_mysql {
   script "location of you python script"      
   interval "the specified interval"                           
   weight 2
}
```

Set the output to 0 or 1 depending on the check

Answer (score 0):

as @nimesh said above, vrrp_script support python script directly. Just put your shell/python/rudy location with the `script "location of you script"` config.